# .m Script for moving multiple .c and .h file from diff folder to singlefolder

Tags: matlab, command, simulink, matlab-guide, auto-generate

How do I move auto generated multiple .c and .h file from different folder to the single folder using .m scripting in MATLAB/Simulink?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called [`movefile`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movefile.html) which allows you to move files in the filesystem. However, you have to pass the location of your *.c and *.h files.

```
%   Moves the file test.txt which is located in the current working
%   directory into the folder "otherFolder"
movefile('./test.txt', '/otherFolder/test.txt', f);
```